# Error retrieving icon: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to add icon's to matIconRegistry and use it in mat-icon

In App Component

```
constructor(
   private _matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
   private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
){
   _matIconRegistry
          .addSvgIcon('notification', this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../assets/svg/icon_notification.svg'));
 }
```

I've also tried like this,

```
 _matIconRegistry
      .addSvgIcon('notification', this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/svg/icon_notification.svg'));
```

}

In my component

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="notification"></mat-icon>
```

But it's throwing error in the console

**Error retrieving icon: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL**

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz demo reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem was occurred due to interceptor and the solution is available in the below link:

The interceptor was blocking ".svg" image from the registry.

https://github.com/czeckd/angular-svg-icon/issues/37

Comment: Duuuuuuuuuuude. I've got crazy trying every possible path, relative and absolute, in every possible style to solve this........ and it actually was the interceptor.... thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In my `AppComponent`, I'm using this method, please note the `'./assets...'` notation, since the `assets` directory is at the same hierarchy level as the `AppComponent`.

```
registerSvgIcon(name: string): void {
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(name, this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/svg-icons/' + name + '.svg'));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. actually my interceptor was blocking me